# Inner Join and left combining to get last row out of a group

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have a data set containing multiple tables which I need to link together to get my desired output.

Table 1 - house_house

```
house_id | Name | address | zipcode
```

Table 2 - house_price

```
ID | house_id | price | status_id
```

Table 3 - house_status

```
ID | name
```

In table 2, there are multiple entries per huis_id, containing either a change in price and/or status. On the query I'm currently trying to construct, I want to get a min/max prijs and also the latest known status.

As I always want to use table 1 to have a complete overview of all locations and trying to join the other tables via a left join to this table.

For the status I need a subquery, which I constructed in an innerjoin. The challenge I run into is that when I run the innerjoin on the price table it works nicely, but combining it on the house table after a left join with the price, I'm struggling to get it working, which makes sense as I'm trying to link tables together which is currently not possible.

Any suggestions how to make this work are more then welcome, as I hit a brick wall with my own thoughts.

Query:

```
SELECT 
     h.address, h.zipcode, p.huis_id, p.status 
FROM 
    house_house h
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
        house_id, status, max(id) as id 
    FROM
        house_price 
    GROUP BY 
        house_id) p1 
ON 
    p.house_id = p1.house_id AND 
    p.id = p1.id
LEFT JOIN 
        house_price p ON p.house_id = h.house_id
GROUP BY 
    p.house_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT hh.house_id
     , hh.name
     , hh.address
     , hh.zipcode
     , hp.ID
     , hp.price
     , hp.status_id
     , hs.name 
  FROM house_house hh 
  LEFT 
  JOIN house_price hp 
    ON hh.house_id = hp.house_id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN house_status hs 
    ON hp.ID=hs.ID
```

Comment: You may want to include some mechanism for identifying house names as distinct from other kinds of names.

Comment: The query runs perfectly, but it returns duplicate rows. @Strawberry has a good point to update the query with the mechanisme to distinct the rows.

Comment: @Strawberry I have updated those, to make sure I can see the difference and use it that way in de code.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from 
(
SELECT h.*, p.*
     , row_number() over (h.house_id order by p.price desc) as hp
     , row_number() over (h.house_id order by p.price asc) as lp
     , row_number() over (h.house_id order by p.is desc) as s
FROM  house_house h
JOIN house_price p
on p.house_id = h.house_id
) tt 
where tt.hp = 1 or tt. lp = 1 or tt.s = 1
```

Comment: possible good option, but I believe mysql isn't supporting the row_number() function

Comment: This is easily achieved with variables